# Is it possible to detect when php file is included?

Tags: php

So in file `first.php` I will include file `original.php` with `include_once`.

Problem occurs, when I try to call functions which are inside `original.php` and that file is not loading if there is no user session.

Basicaly I'm include file `original.php` in which are few functions im calling later in `first.php`, but those functions are inaccesible due to restrictions I've set in `original.php`, but now I want to add rule to `original.php` to allow such requests from `first.php` or any other PHP file that will include `original.php`...

I wonder what could I do in this case OR could I simply add some if clause to `original.php`, like:

```
if($fileIncluded == 'yes')
{
   // do not check if user session exist etc.
}
else
{
   // check for user session
}
```

Thanks for ideas and help in advance!

Comment: Are you're saying that you intentionally don't include `original.php` if there's no user session, or that even though you call `include_once` it doesn't include it if a user session doesn't exist?  That sounds like a bug in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a constant in the file to be included like so:

In `original.php`:

```
define('ORIGINAL_INCLUDED', TRUE);
```

Then in `first.php` you check if the constant exists:

```
if (defined('ORIGINAL_INCLUDED'))
{
    // do not check if user session exist etc.
}
else
{
    // check for user session
}
```

Unlike [get_included_files()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) this will work when a script includes a script. `get_included_files()` will only return the files included in the main script, but not scripts included in child scripts.

Or in `original.php`:

```
if ('original.php' == basename(__FILE__))
{
    // original.php directly accessed
}
else
{
    // original.php included instead
}
```

Comment: +1 for the C-style approach, although it looks a little messy in PHP.

Comment: I would like to detect if file was included in original.php

Comment: @Adrov so you are including `first.php` into `original.php`? If so, see my edit.

Comment: No, I'm including `original.php` in `first.php`, I just want to add a rule / check inside `original.php` if possible, that when file is included and not directly loaded in browser it will skip all checks like (user logged in, administrator session etc.)

I'm not sure if that is possible that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: @Adrov well above should suffice if I am correctly understanding you.

Comment: If you are accessing `original.php` how can you access (directly load) `first.php` at the same time? If you mean you don't want people to directly load `original.php` then do as I have put in my edit at bottom.

Answer (score 2):

PHP provides a **[get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php)** function that would seem to work in this scenario.

```
if in_array('file.php', get_included_files()) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I've updated my original post to explain what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am PHP newbie, but I would do

```
$add_file = require(file.php);
```

and then do

```
if($add_file) {echo "file is aded";} else {echo "file is not added";}
```

Comment: Code has to be in original.php file... :S You understood me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `get_included_files()` or set a variable like this:

```
  // includedfile.php
 $variable = true;

 //index.php
 include 'includedfile.php';

 if(isset($variable)) {
     // file included
 } else {
     // not included
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I've updated my original post to explain what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could also define a constant, and check if it is defined later. Use *define* and *defined* functions for that. I think it's better than using normal variables.

Php doc: http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php and http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php